# Pushing element into vector

Tags: c++, vector

```
template <class T>
class A{
    //...
};

class B{
    //...
};

class C{
    protected:
    vector< A<B> > vec;
    public:
    void f(B *ptr);      
};

C::f(B *ptr){
    vec.push_back(ptr); // gives error
}
```

The line that I'm trying add element into the vector gives compiler error. How can i fix this one?

Comment: can you share the compiler error?

Comment: You don't have a vector of `B*`, you have a vector of `A<B>`. Without more information on what you're trying to accomplish it will be difficult to help.

Comment: Perhaps you should be using inheritance instead of template.  The behavior you want can be obtained through inheritance, `class B` inherits from `class A`.  A `std::vector<A *>` can also hold pointers to `class B`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It expects an A, you give it a B

```
A<B> a;
a.initsomehowwith(*ptr);
vec.push_back(a);
```

Answer (score 6):

You cannot push an element of type `B*` into a vector that is designed to take elements of `A<B>`. What do you want to achieve?

If you just want to make it compile, then (assuming that `B` is copyable):

1. Declare your vector as `vector<B>`.
2. Use `push_back(*B)`. Note that it's not `pushback`.

Answer (score 1):

By sorting out your design. What are you actually trying to do here? You've got a vector of `A<B>`, but you're trying to push in a pointer to B. Are you hoping for some kind of conversion? Your code fundamentally doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you might want is something like this:

```
void C::f(B &ptr){  // reference not a pointer
    A<B> b_in_a(B) ;
    vec.push_back(b_in_a); // gives error
}
```

Make sure that you're copy, assignment and comparison operators are FULLY implements if you're using something other than a pointer in any container template.  Also be aware that unless you use pointers you can't store subclasses in your containers.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/push_back/) the method's name is push_back, and it takes a reference not a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Two mistakes:

- `push_back` takes an underscore.
- You do not have a function that transforms a `B*` into a `A<B>`

Answer (score 0):

`vec` doesn't accept values of type `B*`, you have it defined as `A<B>`.  You can redefine `vec` as:

```
vector< B* > vec;
```

Answer (score 0):

First your vector is storing items of type `A<B>` not `B*`.
Second it's `push_back` not pushback.